# Using a separate testing mongo database on mongo and Heroku

Tags: mongodb, express, heroku

In my project I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-safe in order to declare environment variables needed for configuration. For example:

```
NODE_ENV=development
JWT_SECRET=xxxxxxx
JWT_EXPIRATION_MINUTES=15
MONGO_URI=mongodb://mongodb:27017/proddb
BASE_URI=http://localhost:3000/
MONGO_URI_TESTS=mongodb://mongodb:27017/testdb
PORT=3000
```

Then I use those files in a config file :

```
module.exports = {
  env: process.env.NODE_ENV,
  port: process.env.PORT,
  jwtSecret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  jwtExpirationInterval: process.env.JWT_EXPIRATION_MINUTES,
  mongo: {
    uri: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test'
      ? process.env.MONGO_URI_TESTS
      : process.env.MONGO_URI,
  },
  logs: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'combined' : 'dev',
};
```

and in my package.json file, I've got:

```
   "scripts": {
        "start": "NODE_ENV=production node ./src/index.js",
        "dev": "LOG_LEVEL=debug nodemon --inspect=0.0.0.0 ./src/index.js",
        "test": "NODE_ENV=test nyc --reporter=html --reporter=text mocha --timeout 20000 --recursive src/tests"
    }
```

The problem? Everything works fine but when tests are run on Heroku (prod) , they run on the main database and not on the testdb...

Comment: How did you configure Heroku to run the tests? Do they run pre-start?

Comment: I didn't really... I'm using the default build script they provide without customizations so I'm assuming it runs yarn test before deploying...

Comment: I think that's the thing here: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/blob/master/bin/test

Comment: probably that's the bug: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/issues/504